# Visual studio error code UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I got error when update record

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Could you please see what went wrong. 
This my code:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.PrintersBindingSource1.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(Me.ITPrinterDataSet1)
            MsgBox("Update Successfully.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Code formatting was introduced. I have added a tag for the language used. The question still deserves a bit more information what you are trying to achieve and which technology you are using to communicate with your background data.

Comment: Using data grid to show all records on form in vb (visual studio). Try to update any fields for each record. i think I mess up with data set or data source or columns but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

1- Your table must have at least 1 primary key column.

2- It's better use "update" method of your table adapter not updateall method.

3-Call "EndEdit" method of your bindingsource before update command.

Comment: I did work before. After I added new field and no longer update.

Comment: Send your project so i can check it for you